# Appium on iOS Instruments Crash and Application is crashing

Tags: ios, appium, xcode-instruments

I am trying to automate a scenario where i launch an app on ios Device(can be either simulator or Real Device). The app is getting installed on the Device, but it is crashing and launching. I have set the all the required capabilities and i am launching my code from Eclipse Mars version.

I am getting this error, and app is crashing.

```
 (Original error: Instruments crashed on startup)","origValue":"Instruments crashed on startup"},"sessionId":null}
```

Please find the Capabilities set on device

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "9.1"); 
capabilities.setCapability("deviceName","iPhone 6s Plus");
capabilities.setCapability("platformName","iOS");
capabilities.setCapability("bundleId","com.quinnox.EnterpriseCycleCounting");
capabilities.setCapability("app","/Users/rohinic/Downloads/ComEdApp.ipa");
capabilities.setCapability("fullReset",true);
capabilities.setCapability("launchTimeout","900000");
driver = new IOSDriver<WebElement>(new URL("http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub"),capabilities);
```

The Complete appium log from start to end is as follows,

```
Launching Appium with command: '/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node/bin/node' lib/server/main.js --command-timeout "7200" --debug-log-spacing --platform-version "8.4" --platform-name "iOS" --default-device

info: Welcome to Appium v1.4.13 (REV c75d8adcb66a75818a542fe1891a34260c21f76a)

info: Appium REST http interface listener started on 0.0.0.0:4723

info: [debug] Non-default server args: {"platformName":"iOS","platformVersion":"8.4","defaultDevice":true,"defaultCommandTimeout":7200,"debugLogSpacing":true}

info: Console LogLevel: debug

info: --> POST /wd/hub/session {"desiredCapabilities":{"app":"/Users/rohinic/Downloads/ComEdApp.ipa","nativeInstrumentsLib":true,"platformVersion":"9.1","bundleId":"com.quinnox.EnterpriseCycleCounting","platformName":"iOS","deviceName":"iPhone 6s Plus","fullReset":true,"launchTimeout":900000}}

info: Client User-Agent string: Apache-HttpClient/4.3.3 (java 1.5)

info: *************************************
info: *************************************
info: *************************************
info: *************************************
info: *************************************
info: *************************************
info: *************************************
info: *************************************
info: ****        NEW SESSION           ***
info: ****        NEW SESSION           ***
info: ****        NEW SESSION           ***
info: ****        NEW SESSION           ***
info: ****        NEW SESSION           ***
info: ****        NEW SESSION           ***
info: ****        NEW SESSION           ***
info: ****        NEW SESSION           ***
info: *************************************

info: *************************************
info: *************************************
info: *************************************
info: *************************************
info: *************************************
info: *************************************
info: *************************************

info: [debug] Using local .ipa from desired caps: /Users/rohinic/Downloads/ComEdApp.ipa
info: [debug] Copying local zip to tmp dir

info: [debug] /Users/rohinic/Downloads/ComEdApp.ipa copied to /var/folders/y_/rh25732s5pl00xxr9s99yybh0000gq/T/116116-5001-qlbbdy/appium-app.zip

info: [debug] Unzipping /var/folders/y_/rh25732s5pl00xxr9s99yybh0000gq/T/116116-5001-qlbbdy/appium-app.zip

info: [debug] Testing zip archive: /var/folders/y_/rh25732s5pl00xxr9s99yybh0000gq/T/116116-5001-qlbbdy/appium-app.zip

info: [debug] Zip archive tested clean

info: [debug] Unzip successful

info: [debug] Using locally extracted app: /var/folders/y_/rh25732s5pl00xxr9s99yybh0000gq/T/116116-5001-qlbbdy/Payload/ComEdApp.app

info: [debug] Creating new appium session b976d2cd-1a6e-4b96-805c-16ccb15d1576
info: [debug] Removing any remaining instruments sockets
info: [debug] Cleaned up instruments socket /tmp/instruments_sock
info: [debug] Setting Xcode version

info: [debug] Xcode version set to 7.2.1

info: [debug] Setting iOS SDK Version

info: [debug] iOS SDK Version set to 9.2

info: [debug] Checking whether instruments supports our device string
info: [debug] Getting list of devices instruments supports

info: [debug] Instruments is at: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/instruments

info: [debug] Getting device string from opts: {"forceIphone":false,"forceIpad":false,"xcodeVersion":"7.2.1","iOSSDKVersion":"9.2","deviceName":"iPhone 6s Plus","platformVersion":"9.1"}

info: [debug] fixDevice is on
info: [debug] Final device string is: 'iPhone 6s Plus (9.1)'
info: [debug] iOS sim UDID is 0C8498DB-281C-49D4-A81D-0049133A28C5
info: [debug] Auto-detecting iOS udid...
info: [debug] Not auto-detecting udid, running on sim

info: [debug] Could not parse plist file (as binary) at /var/folders/y_/rh25732s5pl00xxr9s99yybh0000gq/T/116116-5001-qlbbdy/Payload/ComEdApp.app/en.lproj/Localizable.strings
info: Will try to parse the plist file as XML
info: [debug] Could not parse plist file (as XML) at /var/folders/y_/rh25732s5pl00xxr9s99yybh0000gq/T/116116-5001-qlbbdy/Payload/ComEdApp.app/en.lproj/Localizable.strings
warn: Could not parse app Localizable.strings assuming it doesn't exist
info: [debug] Creating instruments
info: [debug] Preparing uiauto bootstrap
info: [debug] Dynamic bootstrap dir: /Users/rohinic/Library/Application Support/appium/bootstrap
info: [debug] Dynamic env: {"nodePath":"/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node/bin/node","commandProxyClientPath":"/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/submodules/appium-uiauto/bin/command-proxy-client.js","instrumentsSock":"/tmp/instruments_sock","interKeyDelay":null,"justLoopInfinitely":false,"autoAcceptAlerts":false,"autoDismissAlerts":false,"sendKeyStrategy":"oneByOne"}
 info: [debug] Dynamic bootstrap code: // This file is automatically generated. Do not manually modify!

info: [debug] Dynamic bootstrap path: /Users/rohinic/Library/Application Support/appium/bootstrap/bootstrap-f062718992d59810.js
info: [debug] Reusing dynamic bootstrap: /Users/rohinic/Library/Application Support/appium/bootstrap/bootstrap-f062718992d59810.js
info: [debug] Getting device string from opts: {"forceIphone":false,"forceIpad":false,"xcodeVersion":"7.2.1","iOSSDKVersion":"9.2","deviceName":"iPhone 6s Plus","platformVersion":"9.1"}
info: [debug] fixDevice is on
info: [debug] Final device string is: 'iPhone 6s Plus (9.1)'
info: [debug] We're on iOS7.1+ so forcing defaultDevice on
info: [debug] Getting device string from opts: {"forceIphone":false,"forceIpad":false,"xcodeVersion":"7.2.1","iOSSDKVersion":"9.2","deviceName":"iPhone 6s Plus","platformVersion":"9.1"}
info: [debug] fixDevice is on
info: [debug] Final device string is: 'iPhone 6s Plus (9.1)'
info: [debug] Could not parse plist file (as binary) at /var/folders/y_/rh25732s5pl00xxr9s99yybh0000gq/T/116116-5001-qlbbdy/Payload/ComEdApp.app/Info.plist
info: Will try to parse the plist file as XML

info: [debug] Parsed app Info.plist (as XML)

info: [debug] Wrote new app Info.plist with device type

info: [debug] Checking whether we need to set app preferences
info: [debug] Running ios sim reset flow
info: [debug] Killing the simulator process

info: [debug] Killing any other simulator daemons

info: [debug] Cleaning sim data files

info: node-simctl: Executing: xcrun with args: simctl erase 0C8498DB-281C-49D4-A81D-0049133A28C5 and timeout: 2000

info: [debug] Killall iOS Simulator

info: [debug] Cleaning app data files

warn: Applications directory /Users/rohinic/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/0C8498DB-281C-49D4-A81D-0049133A28C5/data/Containers/Data/Application doesn't exist. Have you run this simulator before?

warn: Applications directory /Users/rohinic/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/0C8498DB-281C-49D4-A81D-0049133A28C5/data/Containers/Bundle/Application doesn't exist. Have you run this simulator before?

info: Couldn't find app directories to delete. Probably it's not installed 

info: [debug] Resetting Content and Settings for Simulator 

info: node-simctl: Executing: xcrun with args: simctl erase 0C8498DB-281C-49D4-A81D-0049133A28C5 and timeout: 2000

info: [debug] Not setting locale

info: [debug] No iOS / app preferences to set

info: [debug] Starting iOS 8.* simulator log capture

info: [debug] Not pre-launching simulator
info: [debug] Starting command proxy.
info: [debug] Instruments socket server started at /tmp/instruments_sock
info: [debug] Starting instruments

info: [debug] Instruments is at: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/instruments
info: Launching instruments
info: [debug] Attempting to run app on iPhone 6s Plus (9.1)
info: [debug] Spawning instruments with command: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/instruments -t /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Instruments.app/Contents/PlugIns/AutomationInstrument.xrplugin/Contents/Resources/Automation.tracetemplate -D /tmp/appium-instruments/instrumentscli0.trace -w "iPhone 6s Plus (9.1)" /var/folders/y_/rh25732s5pl00xxr9s99yybh0000gq/T/116116-5001-qlbbdy/Payload/ComEdApp.app -e UIASCRIPT "/Users/rohinic/Library/Application Support/appium/bootstrap/bootstrap-f062718992d59810.js" -e UIARESULTSPATH /tmp/appium-instruments
info: [debug] And extra without-delay env: {}
info: [debug] And launch timeouts (in ms): {"global":900000}

info: [debug] [INST] Waiting for device to boot...

info: [debug] [INST STDERR] 2016-02-16 20:02:58.934 instruments[5040:85669] WebKit Threading Violation - initial use of WebKit from a secondary thread.

info: [debug] [INST STDERR] 2016-02-16 20:03:44.216 instruments[5040:86416] Attempting to change event horizon while disengage
info: [debug] [INST STDERR] 2016-02-16 20:03:44.217 instruments[5040:86958] Attempting to change event horizon while disengage

info: [debug] [INST STDERR] Instruments Trace Error : Target failed to run: The operation couldn’t be completed. (FBSOpenApplicationErrorDomain error 1.) : Failed to launch process with bundle identifier 'com.quinnox.EnterpriseCycleCounting'

info: [debug] [INSTSERVER] Instruments exited with code 253
info: [debug] Killall instruments
info: [debug] Instruments crashed on startup
info: [debug] Attempting to retry launching instruments, this is retry #1
info: [debug] Killall iOS Simulator

info: Launching instruments

info: [debug] Attempting to run app on iPhone 6s Plus (9.1)

info: [debug] Spawning instruments with command: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/instruments -t /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Instruments.app/Contents/PlugIns/AutomationInstrument.xrplugin/Contents/Resources/Automation.tracetemplate -D /tmp/appium-instruments/instrumentscli0.trace -w "iPhone 6s Plus (9.1)" /var/folders/y_/rh25732s5pl00xxr9s99yybh0000gq/T/116116-5001-qlbbdy/Payload/ComEdApp.app -e UIASCRIPT "/Users/rohinic/Library/Application Support/appium/bootstrap/bootstrap-f062718992d59810.js" -e UIARESULTSPATH /tmp/appium-instruments
info: [debug] And extra without-delay env: {}
info: [debug] And launch timeouts (in ms): {"global":900000}

info: [debug] [INST STDERR] 2016-02-16 20:03:52.554 instruments[5155:87070] WebKit Threading Violation - initial use of WebKit from a secondary thread.

info: [debug] [INST STDERR] 2016-02-16 20:03:58.268 instruments[5155:87128] Attempting to change event horizon while disengage

info: [debug] [INST STDERR] 2016-02-16 20:03:58.268 instruments[5155:87129] Attempting to change event horizon while disengage
info: [debug] [INST STDERR] Instruments Trace Error : Target failed to run: The operation couldn’t be completed. (FBSOpenApplicationErrorDomain error 1.) : Failed to launch process with bundle identifier 'com.quinnox.EnterpriseCycleCounting'

info: [debug] [INSTSERVER] Instruments exited with code 253
info: [debug] Killall instruments
info: [debug] Instruments crashed on startup
info: [debug] Attempting to retry launching instruments, this is retry #2
info: [debug] Killall iOS Simulator

info: Launching instruments

info: [debug] Attempting to run app on iPhone 6s Plus (9.1)

info: [debug] Spawning instruments with command: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/instruments -t /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Instruments.app/Contents/PlugIns/AutomationInstrument.xrplugin/Contents/Resources/Automation.tracetemplate -D /tmp/appium-instruments/instrumentscli0.trace -w "iPhone 6s Plus (9.1)" /var/folders/y_/rh25732s5pl00xxr9s99yybh0000gq/T/116116-5001-qlbbdy/Payload/ComEdApp.app -e UIASCRIPT "/Users/rohinic/Library/Application Support/appium/bootstrap/bootstrap-f062718992d59810.js" -e UIARESULTSPATH /tmp/appium-instruments
info: [debug] And extra without-delay env: {}
info: [debug] And launch timeouts (in ms): {"global":900000}

info: [debug] [INST STDERR] 2016-02-16 20:04:06.714 instruments[5179:87396] WebKit Threading Violation - initial use of WebKit from a secondary thread.

info: [debug] [INST STDERR] 2016-02-16 20:04:12.090 instruments[5179:87332] Attempting to change event horizon while disengage
info: [debug] [INST STDERR] 2016-02-16 20:04:12.090 instruments[5179:87401] Attempting to change event horizon while disengage

info: [debug] [INST STDERR] Instruments Trace Error : Target failed to run: The operation couldn’t be completed. (FBSOpenApplicationErrorDomain error 1.) : Failed to launch process with bundle identifier 'com.quinnox.EnterpriseCycleCounting'

info: [debug] [INSTSERVER] Instruments exited with code 253
info: [debug] Killall instruments
info: [debug] Instruments crashed on startup
info: [debug] Attempting to retry launching instruments, this is retry #3
info: [debug] Killall iOS Simulator

info: Launching instruments

info: [debug] Attempting to run app on iPhone 6s Plus (9.1)
info: [debug] Spawning instruments with command: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/instruments -t /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Instruments.app/Contents/PlugIns/AutomationInstrument.xrplugin/Contents/Resources/Automation.tracetemplate -D /tmp/appium-instruments/instrumentscli0.trace -w "iPhone 6s Plus (9.1)" /var/folders/y_/rh25732s5pl00xxr9s99yybh0000gq/T/116116-5001-qlbbdy/Payload/ComEdApp.app -e UIASCRIPT "/Users/rohinic/Library/Application Support/appium/bootstrap/bootstrap-f062718992d59810.js" -e UIARESULTSPATH /tmp/appium-instruments
info: [debug] And extra without-delay env: {}
info: [debug] And launch timeouts (in ms): {"global":900000}

info: [debug] [INST STDERR] 2016-02-16 20:04:19.058 instruments[5203:87596] WebKit Threading Violation - initial use of WebKit from a secondary thread.

info: [debug] [INST STDERR] 2016-02-16 20:04:24.402 instruments[5203:87596] Attempting to change event horizon while disengage

info: [debug] [INST STDERR] 2016-02-16 20:04:24.402 instruments[5203:87621] Attempting to change event horizon while disengage
info: [debug] [INST STDERR] Instruments Trace Error : Target failed to run: The operation couldn’t be completed. (FBSOpenApplicationErrorDomain error 1.) : Failed to launch process with bundle identifier 'com.quinnox.EnterpriseCycleCounting'

info: [debug] [INSTSERVER] Instruments exited with code 253
info: [debug] Killall instruments
info: [debug] Instruments crashed on startup
info: [debug] We exceeded the number of retries allowed for instruments to successfully start; failing launch
info: [debug] Stopping iOS log capture
info: [debug] Running ios sim reset flow
info: [debug] Killing the simulator process
info: [debug] Killing any other simulator daemons
info: [debug] Killall iOS Simulator

info: [debug] Cleaning sim data files

info: node-simctl: Executing: xcrun with args: simctl erase 0C8498DB-281C-49D4-A81D-0049133A28C5 and timeout: 2000

info: node-simctl: Executing: xcrun with args: simctl erase 0C8498DB-281C-49D4-A81D-0049133A28C5 and timeout: 2000

info: node-simctl: Executing: xcrun with args: simctl erase 0C8498DB-281C-49D4-A81D-0049133A28C5 and timeout: 2000

info: node-simctl: Executing: xcrun with args: simctl erase 0C8498DB-281C-49D4-A81D-0049133A28C5 and timeout: 2000

info: [debug] Cleaning app data files

warn: Applications directory /Users/rohinic/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/0C8498DB-281C-49D4-A81D-0049133A28C5/data/Containers/Data/Application doesn't exist. Have you run this simulator before?
warn: Applications directory /Users/rohinic/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/0C8498DB-281C-49D4-A81D-0049133A28C5/data/Containers/Bundle/Application doesn't exist. Have you run this simulator before?
info: Couldn't find app directories to delete. Probably it's not installed
info: [debug] Resetting Content and Settings for Simulator

info: node-simctl: Executing: xcrun with args: simctl erase 0C8498DB-281C-49D4-A81D-0049133A28C5 and timeout: 2000

info: [debug] Cleaning up appium session

error: Failed to start an Appium session, err was: Error: Instruments crashed on startup

info: [debug] Error: Instruments crashed on startup at [object Object].Instruments.onInstrumentsExit (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/submodules/appium-instruments/lib/instruments.js:440:31) at [object Object].<anonymous> (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/submodules/appium-instruments/lib/instruments.js:353:12) at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17) at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1074:12)

info: [debug] Responding to client with error: {"status":33,"value":{"message":"A new session could not be created. (Original error: Instruments crashed on startup)","origValue":"Instruments crashed on startup"},"sessionId":null}
info: <-- POST /wd/hub/session 500 99826.842 ms - 182
```

Kindly help me in automating this script. Thank you:)

Comment: I think your real error is this: `info: [debug] [INST STDERR] Instruments Trace Error : Target failed to run: The operation couldn’t be completed. (FBSOpenApplicationErrorDomain error 1.) : Failed to launch process with bundle identifier 'com.quinnox.EnterpriseCycleCounting'` . Try removing the bundleId capability (it's optional anyway) and running your test.

Comment: @econoMichael: Yes, i removed bundle id from the capabiltity. Still i am getting the error.

Comment: you removed the bundleId and still getting `info: [debug] [INST STDERR] Instruments Trace Error : Target failed to run: The operation couldn’t be completed. (FBSOpenApplicationErrorDomain error 1.) : Failed to launch process with bundle identifier 'com.quinnox.EnterpriseCycleCounting'`?

Comment: yes.. Still getting the same error. and it says instruments crashed with code 253. And on simulator as well as on real device, i see application launching and crashing.